# Can I ignore caching of a plugin in W3 Total Cache?

Tags: plugins, widgets, cache, plugin-w3-total-cache

I currently have a plugin that lets me display a random post in a widget. The problem is that if I activate w3 total cache it will only display that post as long as the cache hasn't been cleared. Is there a way to cache everything except this plugin?

Sorry if the question is rather newbie, I just installed the plugin but haven't been able to find the answer anywhere.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try fragment caching, from plugin's FAQ:

```
Edit your templates to with the following syntax to ensure that dynamic features remain so:
Example 1:
<!-- mfunc any PHP code --><!-- /mfunc -->
Example 2:
<!-- mfunc -->any PHP code<!-- /mfunc -->
Example 3:
<!--MFUNC           -->
                                      echo rand();
<!--/mfunc -->
Example 4:
<!-- mclude path/to/file.php --><!-- /mclude -->
Example 5:
<!-- mclude -->path/to/file.php<!-- /mclude -->
```

But my personal opinion is just to get rid of overly dynamic stuff. Unless it's key functionality (like in e-commerce) it's usually useless eye candy.

Comment: I understand, the problem is that this random post displays a random featured ad that users pay to have it there, if I only display 1 it loses the whole purpose. Let me test that approach, thanks a lot.

Comment: Sorry the above didn't work, I don't know if I might be doing it wrong. What I wanted to do was basically disable cache on my sidebar so I did: <!-- mclude --> <div id="sidebar"> //Sidebar content </div> <!-- /mclude --> But it still caches it.

Comment: @javiervd `mclude` is for including files, try wrapping code in `mfunc` ones (examples 2-3).

Comment: Thanks @Rast, using mfunc throwed me an error but I used <!-- mclude /wp-content/themes/mytheme/sidebar.php --><!-- /mclude --> and it worked just fine.

Comment: <!-- mfunc PHPCODE --><!-- /mfunc --> doesn't (seem) to work for plugins. When I do this, my page doesn't actually contain the code I expect.

Comment: Okay, figured out the issue. I need to place the <!-- mfunc --> inside the body of the function: https://gist.github.com/balasuar/5118348